# Comments on posts with new custom post type redirected to another post

Tags: custom-post-types, comments

I've ran into a strange problem today.

I created a new custom post type, "blog". Everything appears to be working correctly. However, when I make a new comment on a post under this new custom post type, the comment is instead sent to another post of mine, which is of the default type.

The comments show on *all* posts of the new custom type, *and* on the old post. The backend shows no comments on any posts of the custom post type, however.

Deleting the old post which recieves the comments simply assigns another old post as the unlucky reciever.

The comment submit button points to the wrong ID on all posts of the new custom post type.

What's going on? How do I even begin to debug this?

Comment: Have you customised the comment form at all? Or are you using a theme that does? How was this post type registered? Where is the comment form, on the single page or list page? Have you implemented the post type properly with the [correct loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/#using-the-loop) and not a custom query?

Comment: @JacobPeattie

The comment form is being rendered with comment_form(), with some slight additions to the HTML - nothing that should interfere with this. 

The post type was registered using the CPT UI plugin.

The comment form is on a single page, not a list page.

I'm pretty sure I've used the loop correctly, but I'll take a closer look.

Comment: The CPT UI plugin has, if I'm remembering correctly, about 50% of the functionality available to actual CPTs.  You've probably attempted something the CPT UI devs never even considered.

Comment: Did you enable 'comments' in the Supports section when making the CPT in CPT UI?